# How to pass a full YUV (YpCbCr) 4:2:0 frame to opengl

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, avfoundation, yuv

The native colorspace of the iphone 3gs camera is YpCbCr 4:2:0. I plan to do a lot of luminance processing in opengl (though I will do a bit of color as well). Is there an efficient way of getting the frame to opengl?

I've been successful glteximage2d'ing with GL_LUMINANCE to get just the luminance. I've not been successful with another glteximage2d pass for just the color data. Is there a better way other than doing two passes? If not, is it even worth it?

Answer (score 4):

I implemented this by putting each channel into a own GL_LUMINANCE texture and do the colour space conversion in the fragment shader.

Comment: Presumably the use of three different textures was so that you could directly upload the buffer AVFoundation returned, without having to byte shuffle on the CPU?

Comment: Sounds like it would work, but wonder if it's worth it performance-wise due to the extra gltextimage2d calls.

Comment: @Tommy: Actually I'm using three different textures to allow for different spatial resolution in the channels, like you have it in chroma subsampled formats (YpCbCr 4:2:0 is such a format). The german wikipedia has a nice diagram showing the different modi: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farbunterabtastung#Bezeichnungsschema Instead of a shader one could also use a clever combination of multiple passes and blending modi, but frankly: A shader is easier to implement and performs better on current hardware.